# Problems with quiver function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, plot, shift

I am struggling with the **quiver function** in MATLAB.
The thing is, that I want the directions of the arrows be **shifted by 90 degrees**.
So when the derived angle is zero degrees, the vector arrows in the plot should point downwards instead of to the right as pre-defined in the quiver function.

Any suggestions, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a 90-degree turn, you only have to interchange `u` and `v` and add a minus sign.

Consider the following example:

```
[x y] = ndgrid(-1:.2:1);
u = 1+x - 2*y.^2;
v = -x.^2 - y;
```

Normal figure:

```
quiver(x,y,u,v) %// normal
axis([-1.5 1.5 -1.5 1.5])
```

[image]

Vectors turned 90 degrees:

```
quiver(x,y,v,-u) %// 90 degree turn. quiver(x,y,-v,u) for turning the other way
axis([-1.5 1.5 -1.5 1.5])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this can be surprisingly simple.

I believe you are looking for this:

```
 camroll(90)
```

Just make your quiver plot and then execute this command.

Comment: unfortunately no. My quiver plot is plotted over a M x N **imagesc plot** which has the correct orientation. I know that my problem can be solved when I derive the angle like `phi(x,z) = -1 * atan2(XVec(x,z) / - ZVec(x,z)) * 180 / pi`. But how can I use this information for my quiver plot?